# SQL table for list of transactions - sorting required?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

The general question here - for SQL, can I rely on 'latest entry is always at the highest index' or something to that effect?

Specifically, I'm using sqlalchemy (python-based ORM) and an sqlite database (sqlite_autoincrement=True) to keep track of withdrawals and returns for some items. I have a 'Loans' table for this. It seems to me that all new entries (always done through ORM in python) are appended at a higher primary key index. Is this reliable behaviour, and does it carry over to other SQL databases?

Phrased another way, if I want to check whether an item was most recently returned or loaned out, I would simply do a query on the Loan table for all the occurrences of that item, can I take the 'last' returned row to be the one which was most recently added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't ever rely on such behavior, ever! Any guarantee should be provided by the logical (relational) model, not the engine which can be treated as a black box. If you need to find the "last" entered item you need to rely on a field which is guaranteed by the model to hold such a value: an identity column or a sequence.

Comment: So I guess the implicit question to your answer is 'does this ORM (sqlalchemy) provide any such guarantee'? And for sqlite with autoincrement, I think it may (not very sure, and hoping for someone to tell me so). If it does, does that mean I should rely on this behavior, or should I still be inserting tracker units (for my context, date and time) in every row for sorting?

Comment: I don't think that it is the ORM's job to do such a thing. If the database does not support this out of the box then it will be your application's responsibility to implement such a mechanism. Anyway, I think `autoincrement`, although the documentation seems to suggest against using it unless necessary, will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an AUTOINCREMENT column, SQLite [guarantees](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) that the sequence of IDs is monotonically increasing.

However, if the time of withdrawals/returns is important, it would be a better idea to store that time in the database.